# Unable to download SLURM - sacctmgr issue

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to set up SLURM on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL. When I tried to install, I recieved the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install slurm-wlm

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
      slurm-wlm is already the newest version (17.11.2-1build1).
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     slurm-wlm : Depends: slurm-client (= 17.11.2-1build1) but it is not going to be installed
     slurmctld : Depends: slurm-client (= 17.11.2-1build1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried fixing the install with the code below but it also provided an error.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install 

  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  Correcting dependencies... Done
  The following additional packages will be installed:
    slurm-client
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    slurm-client
  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
  6 not fully installed or removed.
  Need to get 0 B/870 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 1935 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
  (Reading database ... 81615 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to unpack .../slurm-client_17.11.2-1build1_amd64.deb ...
  Unpacking slurm-client (17.11.2-1build1) ...
  dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/slurm-client_17.11.2-1build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
    unable to install new version of '/usr/bin/sacctmgr': File exists
  Errors were encountered while processing:
    /var/cache/apt/archives/slurm-client_17.11.2-1build1_amd64.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to locate the file but cannot find it anywhere within the system. The following code:

```
ls -ld /usr/bin/sacctmgr /usr/bin/
```

Produced the following error message:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/sacctmgr': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 23:16 /usr/bin/
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide!

Comment: Did you `ls -ld /usr/bin/sacctmgr  /usr/bin`?

Comment: @waltinator I just did, here is the resulting message: 

'ls -ld /usr/bin/sacctmgr /usr/bin/'
'ls: cannot access usr/bin/sacctmgr: No such file or directory'
'drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 30 23:16 /usr/bin/'

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add properly formatted information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator sorry aboout that, I've taken your advice and was sure to specific indicating how the post was updated for future reference

Comment: The command `apt-cache search sacctmgr` will show which package you need to install to get `sacctmgr`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 WSL, I was actually able to search the sub-directories leading into the Ubuntu subsystem, find the file, and delete it.

Everything for me is saved in the default /mnt/ folder in my Windows system, so I was able to locate it in my file as per the set-up instructions for the Ubuntu WSL.